# I am trying to make have my javascript tell me if the place is open or closed but it is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to javascript and having my problems, the place is open different on different months so i would like it to be able to read the month and then tell me if its open or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var time = newDate().getHours();
    var opening;
    var month = newDate().getMonth();

    if (month == 0) {
      if (time <= 17) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month == 1) {
      if (time <=18) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 3) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 4) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 5) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 6 ) {
      if (time <=21) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 7) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 8) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 9) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else if (month = 10) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }
    else (month = 11) {
      if (time <=19) {
        opening = "Open";
      }
      else {
        opening = "closed";
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = opening;
</script>
```

I looked up examples but just cant seem to get it

Comment: [Have you checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) That should be the first thing you check when things aren't working.

Comment: You should make sure all the equality comparisons in your if statements use `==`, because more than half of them do not. These two operators are very different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(month = 3)` to `if(month == 3)` for all values from `3` to `11`.  It would work. And you've missed the condition for `month == 2`.

Prefer using `swich()` for such cases. Its mich more clean

Comment: Its working now thank you very much, I was using a switch but then seen an example and they used an else if so i just used that as guidance.

Comment: Cool. If you think this is the right answer, accept it, to help people know about the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- `newDate()` in line 1 and 3 should be `new Date()`
- Use `==` for comparisons instead of `=`, you have missed it in most places: Notice `else if (month = 3) {` vs. `else if (month == 3) {`
- Your last `else` should be an `else if` since you have put a condition there: `else if (month == 11) {`